# Ejabberd 20.0.2 admin panel login form rebound

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I downloaded ejabberd 20.0.2 and successfully installed it, using my pc as a local domain and successfully getting an admin registered. But after I started the ejabberd server, I am having issues logging into the admin panel as I keep getting back the login form to re-enter admin login credentials even though I kept on entering the rightful admin credentials registered during installation.

Is this a bug in the new ejabberd 20.0.2 version or is there any way around this issue?

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is a good idea to **look at the ejabberd log files** when you find some problem, because they may provide useful information about the problem

> I downloaded ejabberd 20.0.2

I guess you refer to ejabberd 20.02.

> But after I started the ejabberd server, I am having issues logging into the admin panel as I keep getting back the login form to re-enter admin login credentials

For example, I make several **typical mistakes**, and this is what the log file shows:

If I enter a non-registered account:

```
2020-03-25 11:51:52.521656+01:00 [warning] 
Access of <<"user555@localhost">> from <<"::1">> failed with error: <<"inexistent-account">>
```

If I enter only the username. Remember you must provide the full JID:

```
2020-03-25 11:52:02.518156+01:00 [warning] 
Access of <<"user1">> from <<"::1">> failed with error: <<"inexistent-account">>
```

If I enter the correct account JID, including the username and server, but I enter a wrong password:

```
2020-03-25 11:52:16.386589+01:00 [warning] 
Access of <<"user1@localhost">> from <<"::1">> failed with error: <<"bad-password">>
```

> Is this a bug in the new ejabberd 20.0.2 version or is there any way around this issue?

So, I think this is not a bug in ejabberd 20.02, you simply forgot to provide the full JID.

But then comes **another problem**: there is also a bug in ejabberd 20.02. When trying to visit the webadmin page, after you provide valid credentials, ejabberd crashes and this is logged:

```
2020-03-25 12:04:13.965151+01:00 [error] CRASH REPORT:
  crasher:
    initial call: ejabberd_http:init/3
    pid: <0.675.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception error: bad argument
      in function  maps:from_list/1
         called as maps:from_list([html])
```

This bug will be fixed in ejabberd 20.03 that will be released in the next hours/days.

So, summarizing in your case:

- Always look at the log files: they may provide useful information
- In the webadmin, provide the full JID, not only username: kuraj@example.org or whatever
- There is a bug in ejabberd 20.02 that breaks the webadmin after login. You can use 20.01, or wait a few hours/days for 20.03. Or you can compile ejabberd from source code.

Comment: Thanks but the only log I have is the install.log file and it have no further logging events since after the installation of the ejabberd server. However, I have been using the rightful username and password to access the admin interface but the process just break without error of "wrong password or any error code" instead it just load and return the login form with username and password of my previous ejabberd server 19.01..